# Laravel Query Builder where is NULL no result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have code as below to get shipment data where `pdf_url` is not `NULL`;

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')->where([
 'shipment_date' => '2017-12-11', ['pdf_url', '<>', 'NULL']])->get();
```

This has no problem, I get the data I need, but when I'm trying to use the same code to get the data with `pdf_url` is `NULL`, it has no result.

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')->where([
 'shipment_date' => '2017-12-11', ['pdf_url', '=', 'NULL']])->get();
```

What do I missing? I am very sure the DB record is there. I also tried other formats but still no result;

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')->where([
 'shipment_date' => '2017-12-11', ['pdf_url', 'NULL']])->get();
```

And

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')->where([
 'shipment_date' => '2017-12-11', 'pdf_url' => 'NULL'])->get();
```

EDIT: I can use `whereRaw`, but I'll prefer to use `where` instead. Code below has no issue;

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')
 ->whereRaw('shipment_date = "2017-12-11" AND pdf_url is NULL')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben thats probably the reason. I guess I have no choice to use `whereNull` or `whereRaw` instead

Answer (score 18):

Use whereNull

```
$shipment_data = DB::table('shipment')
            ->whereNull('pdf_url')->get();
```

Comment: I'm aware of `whereNull` as well as `whereRaw`, I'm just wondering why it doesnt work when I'm using `where` with not NULL is okay

Comment: You can't compare `NULL` using `=`, `<>`, etc. but rather you must use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen pointed exactly the same thing

Answer (score 3):

**try this:**

```php
$records = DB::table('shipment')
  ->where('shipment_date','2017-12-11')
  ->whereNull('pdf_url')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use whereNull

```
The whereNull method verifies that the value of the given column is NULL.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries